# Free calculus book

Tags: calculus, book-recommendation

What is the best calculus book(s) which is free and legal to download? Actually, I study it by myself I don't exactly know what is the "best".

Comment: Look for Paul's online notes for a text alternative.

Comment: Might be able to find something useful [here](https://github.com/rossant/awesome-math)